# Align rendered option text in a select tag

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="catId">Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="catId" ng-model="intCategory" 
                        ng-options="c.Id as c.Category for c in intCategories">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

I am using bootstrap for css and angularjs to render the options.  Everything is working except that the option text appears to be aligned to the left.  How can I center the option text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well seems like if I include a display of inline-block in the parent div tag it then works. Really weird.

Here is the updated html:

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                <label for="catId">Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="catId" ng-model="intCategory" 
                        ng-options="c.Id as c.Category for c in intCategories">
                    <option class="" value="">--Select--</option>
                </select>
              </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using "**text-center**" class, like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="catId">Category</label>
    <select class="form-control text-center" id="catId" ng-model="intCategory" ng-options="c.Id as c.Category for c in intCategories">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

or

```
<option class="text-center" value="">--Select--</option>
```

It works fine with Bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah I tried both of those already.  Seems like something is causing a conflict.